# C# ?: Expression

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have a function with multiple if's (**THIS IS NOT THE ACTUAL CODE**)

```
if(n == 1)
   m = 1;
if(n == 2)
   m = 2;
if(n == 3)
   m = 3;
```

Instead of that I wanted to do make them all into ?: expression :

```
(n == 1) ? m = 1;
```

But it says that its expecting a ':'

I am familiar with the ?: expression from C++ where you can simply write:

```
(n == 1) ? m = 1 : 0;
```

But 0 doesn't take here. This is a ridiculous question and I couldn't even find an answer in google since it ignores '?:' as a word.

**ANSWER** : too bad the answer was in the comments. There is no way to "do nothing" in this expression and I should use if-else or switch. thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's hard to Google a question mark. This is called a ternary operator.

Comment: An "if" statement *executes a statement if a condition is met*. A conditional expression *chooses an expression to evaluate if a condition is met*, and in C# it *must do something with that expression*. (Unlike in C++, where the expression can be executed for its side effects.) You're mixing the two styles together in a strange way; don't do that. It is usually impossible, and when it is possible, it is very confusing. Use a switch, or an if-else; that is much more readable.

Comment: @DOK: It is called a *conditional* operator. It happens to be the only ternary operator in C#, so people sometimes call it "the ternary operator" because there is only one. But it is better to describe a thing based on its *purpose* than its *form*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the ternary operator work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463155/how-does-the-ternary-operator-work)

Comment: There are two questions here. The first is *how does the operator `?:` work in C#?* The second is *what's the best way to express the logic represented in this chain of `if` statements?* IMHO, the answer to the second question is not to use `?:`.

Comment: [Sample code](http://sscce.org/) should be representative as well as complete and concise. The given sample isn't a good representation. Consider picking a [meaningful username](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints). One advantage to this is others can use [at-replies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) and you'll get a notification that someone has addressed you in a comment.

Answer (score 14):

It looks like you're looking for:

```
m = (n == 1) ? 1 : 0;
```

Which you could then cascade to:

```
m = (n == 1) ? 1 : (n == 2) ? 2 : (n == 3) ? 3 : 0;
```

**An important (to me, anyway), aside:**

*Why* are you asking this? If it's because you think that this form will be more efficient than a series of `if` statements, or a `switch`, **don't**. The C# compiler and the .net JIT compiler are really quite clever and they'll transform your code (hopefully!) into its most optimal form. Write your code so its as **understandable by yourself, or the developer who has to maintain it after you** as it can be. If the performance you get isn't acceptable, then try changing it around but **measure** to determine what works best (bearing in mind that newer compilers/.net frameworks could well change what happens).

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize you could chain them together.

Comment: @DOK - you can, doesn't mean it makes for anything other than horribly un-readable code though! ;=)

Comment: @Rob [It doesn't have to be](http://pastebin.com/0kHXD1Hd). Not sure if C# has `#define`, but that's what I do in C/C++.

Comment: @CodeInChaos [It does.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt3yck0x(v=vs.71).aspx) But it can't be used for macros.

Comment: @ Pubby C# doesn't have macros, so you can't do this in C#. @GameZelda Thanks, my comment was a bit sloppy.

Comment: @Rob proper nesting is the solution to this ugly code. Blowing out a sequence of ifs like that can be just as unreadable, imho

Answer (score 2):

looking for **ternary operator in c#** will give you relevant results.

an example usage would be

```
var m = n == 1 ? 1 : 0
```

Comment: The conditional operator `?:` is a ternary operator, because it takes three parameters. I wouldn't call it *the* ternary operator, even if C# currently happens to have only one of them.

Comment: I think this should be a comment.

Comment: I suggest *ternary conditional operator*.

Comment: the questioner said he couldnt find relevant info on google. ternary operator in c# will give you a lot more info to chew on.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe:

```
m = (n == 1) ? 1 : (n == 2) ? 2 : (n == 3) ? 3 : m;
```

or

```
m = n
```

**Edit:**
Simplified:

```
variable2 = (variable1 == value) ?
             variable1 :
             variable2;
```

Comment: @user779444 Not a really good example. And it's pretty easy to understand how to do it from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could write:

```
m = (n==1) ? 1 : m;
```

But IMO that's harder to read and uglier than the original code.

```
(n == 1) ? m = 1 : 0;
```

This isn't allowed because C# doesn't allow arbitrary expressions as a statement. Method calls and assignments are allowed, most other expressions aren't.

A statement is executed for its side-effects, an expression for its value. So it's only natural that the outermost part of a statement has a side effect. `?:` never has a side-effect, so it's not allowed as a statement.

Answer (score 1):

You want this:

`m = (n == 1) ? 1 : 0;`

To nest them all it would look like this:

`m = (n == 1) ? 1 : (n == 2) ? 2 : (n == 3) ? 3 : 0;`

But as you can see, this is really a lot less easy to read and understand.  It can help to add extra parenthesis, but I think you're better off using an if-else tree.

Answer (score 1):

```
m = (n == 1) ? 1 : m
```

Means

> M equals 1 if n == 1, else m

FYI the `?` is called the Ternery operator. Find usage [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
m = (n == 1) ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem to be solved with a ternary if/else operator - it is clearly an ideal candidate for a switch statement (and using a switch is likely to be much more efficient than using a sequence of ternary operators)

If you wish to transliterate an if statement into ?:, then it's quite simple:

```
if ({condition}) {then-code}; else {else-code};
```

becomes

```
{condition} ? {then-code} : {else-code};
```

The only restriction is that the then/else code is a single statement.

The primary benefit of ?: (with modern compilers) is that it can be embedded within a statement to significantly compress the source code - sometimes this can aid readability, and sometimes it just serves to obfuscate the meaning of the code - use it with care.