# How to evaluate Regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

I have come across the following regular expression in a program and struggling to understand what is trying to do. Can anyone help me please? I have only started to learn this

```
l = Z + lo <= lf ? lo : lf - z;
```

Comment: That looks more like a ternary operator

Comment: To be believed. Is this serious?

Comment: The question is not well researched, does not show any steps or effort taken in solving the problem first. That is enough for a downvote, and I didn't even downvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's most likely the use of a ternary operator, despite its cryptic appearance which is usually attributed to RegExps:

```
l = ((z + lo) <= lf) ? lo : (lf - z);
```

This is another way of writing the following:

```
if(z + lo <= lf)
    l = lo;
else
    l = lf - z;
```

This doc covers the ternary operator:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Related SO post:

[How does the ternary operator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463155/how-does-the-ternary-operator-work)

Edit:
The code you posted *can* be used as a [Regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/): http://www.rubular.com/r/Svr9S7EaCP

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. much helpful. I am a bit embarrassed now for mistaking this