# Palindrome.java with methods

Tags: java, palindrome

This program runs without throwing any exceptions, but regardless of the input the result is always the same: ""blank" is a palindrome." Every single time the input is a palindrome I was just wondering if anyone had any advice as to why this is happening? Here is the code for the program:

```
class Palindrome
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int num = 0;
        int dig1 = 0;
        int dig2 = 0;
        int dig3 = 0;
        int dig4 = 0;
        int dig5 = 0;
        boolean digits = true;

        retrieveInput(num);
        check(num,dig1,dig2,dig3,dig4,dig5);
        display(digits,num);
    }

    public static int retrieveInput(int num)
    {
        String number;
        number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter A Five Digit Number.");
        num = Integer.parseInt(number);

        while(num < 9999 || num > 99999)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, num + " Is Not A Five Digit Number",
                "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);        
            number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter A Five Digit Number.");
            num = Integer.parseInt(number);

        }
        return num;
    }

    public static boolean check(int num,int dig1,int dig2,int dig3,int dig4,int dig5)
    {
        boolean digits;

        dig1 = num / 10000;
        dig2 = num % 10000 / 1000;
        dig3 = num % 10000 % 1000 / 100;
        dig4 = num % 10000 % 1000 % 100 /10;
        dig5 = num % 10000 % 1000 % 100 % 10 / 1;

        if (dig1 == dig5 && dig2 == dig4)
            digits = true;
        else
            digits = false;

        return digits;
    }

    public static void display(boolean digits, int num)
    {
        num = retrieveInput(num);
        if (digits = false)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, num + " is a palindrome");
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, num + " is not a palindrome");
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (digits = false)` should be `if (digits == false)` or even better `if (!digits)`. `=` for assignment and `==` for comparison

Comment: I guess you should store the result of the function `check` inside `digits`. That fact that `check` returns a variable named `digits` does not mean that the one inside the main get this value.

Comment: You are returning Boolean value from check function but variable digits is not assigned this value . similarly with retrieve function it is returning a vlue but num is getting initialized. int is passed by value not by reference. Let me know if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the second line of `display(boolean, int)`, you are attempting to compare a boolean with the `=` operator. This *sets* `digits` to `false` I think you meant to say:

```
        if (digits == false)
```

An if statement needs a boolean for input, i.e. `if(bool)`. You don't need to check if this is true or false like `if(bool == true)` because `bool == true` always evaluates to equal `bool`. Saying `bool == true` is completely redundant. However, you `bool == false` always evaluates to the opposite of `bool`. The `!` operator flips the value of the following boolean, e.g. `!true` evaluates to `false`. `!bool` therefore always evaluates to the opposite of `bool`, and is the same as `bool == false`.

Therefore, you only need:

```
        if (!digits)
```

It is also considered good practice to do it this way.

Another way to make your code even shorter is by using the *ternary operator*. This isn't necessarily the best thing to do, but I personally like doing it this way:

Replace

```
if (digits = false)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, num + " is a palindrome");
else
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, num + " is not a palindrome");
```

with

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, num + " is " + (digits ? "not " : "") + "a palindrome");
```

For more about the ternary operator, see these pages:

- [How does the ternary operator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463155/how-does-the-ternary-operator-work)
- [How do I use the conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392932/how-do-i-use-the-conditional-operator)
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Another thing to note is that you don't need to process the input as an integer, because you never use the number in arithmetic statements; you only compare the digits of the number to each other. In this working code, I processed it as a string, so it is much shorter:

```
import javax.swing.*;

class Palindrome
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        display();
    }

    /**
     * Returns a five-digit string
     */
    public static String retrieveInput()
    {
        String number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter A Five Digit Number:"); //get input
        while(number.length() != 5) //continue to get input while it is not five digits
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, number + " Is Not A Five Digit Number",
                "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);        
            number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter A Five Digit Number:");
        }
        return number; //return the input
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether the given five digit string is a palindrome
     */
    public static boolean check(String number)
    {
        return (number.charAt(0) == number.charAt(4) && number.charAt(1) == number.charAt(3)); //checks to see if the first character equals the fifth character and the second character equals the fourth character
    }

    public static void display()
    {
        String number = retrieveInput(); //gets input

        if(check(number)) //if it is a palindrome
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, number + " is a palindrome"); //say it is a palindrome
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, number + " is not a palindrome"); //say it isn't a palindrome
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm I do not understand your answer completly. Agreed, the `=` should be an `==` because it is a comparison and not an assignment. But,  `digits` is set to `false` in case of a not-palindrome. So the check should be inverted, or?

Comment: I seriously doubt that the compiler won't optimize so that run equally fast

Comment: @OskarKjellin Better?

Answer (score 1):

There are several flaws with your code:

```
/* The goal of this method is to receive user input and return the
 * entered value. For this you don't need the num input parameter.
 */
public static int retrieveInput(int num)
{
    String number;
    number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter A Five Digit Number.");
    num = Integer.parseInt(number);

    while(num < 9999 || num > 99999)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, num + " Is Not A Five Digit Number",
            "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);        
        number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter A Five Digit Number.");
        num = Integer.parseInt(number);

    }
    return num;
}

/* Check takes a number and returns if the number is a palindrome or not.
 * The digits of the number are calculated within the method and thus 
 * shouldn't be parameters. (You didn't use these anyway)
 */
public static boolean check(int num,int dig1,int dig2,int dig3,int dig4,int dig5)
{
    boolean digits;

    /* If you removed the paremeters, you've to declare the variables here,
     * e.g. int dig1 = num / 10000
     */
    dig1 = num / 10000;
    dig2 = num % 10000 / 1000;
    dig3 = num % 10000 % 1000 / 100; // This is not needed, because it's not used anywhere
    dig4 = num % 10000 % 1000 % 100 /10;
    dig5 = num % 10000 % 1000 % 100 % 10 / 1;

    /* The pattern you used here is basically
     * if cond == true then return true else return false
     * You never have to use this pattern, since you can
     * directly return conditions
     */
    if (dig1 == dig5 && dig2 == dig4)
        digits = true;
    else
        digits = false;

    return digits;
}

/*
 * This method displays a popup to the user that states if a given number
 * is a palindrome or not. It expects the result and the number as paremeters.
 */
public static void display(boolean digits, int num)
{
    /* You are (again) retrieving the input here, although the input
     * is passed to this method.
     */
    num = retrieveInput(num);

    /* As The Guy with The Hat pointed out in his answer,
     * = is the assignment operator. For comparisons you have to use
     * == instead.
     */
    if (digits = false)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, num + " is a palindrome");
    else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, num + " is not a palindrome");
}

/*
 * Here is the general control flow of your program
 */
public static void main(String args[])
{
    // These variable declarations can be removed, since you aren't using,
    // nor need them.
    int num = 0;
    int dig1 = 0;
    int dig2 = 0;
    int dig3 = 0;
    int dig4 = 0;
    int dig5 = 0;
    boolean digits = true;

    retrieveInput(num); // you are retrieving the input, but not storing it
    check(num,dig1,dig2,dig3,dig4,dig5); // you are checking, but not storing the result
    display(digits,num);
}
```

A corrected version:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int num = retrieveInput();
    boolean isPal = check(num);
    display(num, isPal);
}

public static int retrieveInput() {
    String number = JOptionPane
            .showInputDialog("Enter A Five Digit Number.");
    int num = Integer.parseInt(number);

    while (num < 9999 || num > 99999) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, num
                + " Is Not A Five Digit Number", "ERROR",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter A Five Digit Number.");

    }
    return num;
}

public static boolean check(int num) {
    int dig1 = num / 10000;
    int dig2 = num % 10000 / 1000;
    // int dig3 = num % 10000 % 1000 / 100;
    int dig4 = num % 10000 % 1000 % 100 / 10;
    int dig5 = num % 10000 % 1000 % 100 % 10 / 1;

    return dig1 == dig5 && dig2 == dig4
}

public static void display(int num, boolean isPal) {
    if (isPal)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, num + " is a palindrome");
    else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, num + " is not a palindrome");
}
```

Please notice that I basically didn't change the core of your program. As next steps you might want to check if a user entered non-numerical characters or allow n-length numbers.

Comment: I had a feeling there were more errors throughout the code. Thanks for taking the time to help me out.