# Why does b get the value 100?

Tags: c

**This is on C:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a=100,b;
    b= (a>100)?a++:a--;
    printf("%d %d\n",a,b);
}
```

b assigned the value 100 but when trying

```
int main()
{
    int a=100,b;
    b= (a>100)
    printf("%d %d\n",a,b);
}
```

b prints the value 1 as it returns true.
why is it different when using '?:' operator?

Comment: Actually, the second example sets `b` to `0`. See [here](https://onlinegdb.com/B11oMThBV).

Comment: Um... But your code sample are completely different. Why does it surprise you that they do different things?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the ternary operator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463155/how-does-the-ternary-operator-work) and [How do I use the conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/392932/62576)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `?:` operator evaluates either the thing before the `:` or the thing after the `:` to determine what it evaluates to. In this case, `(a>100)` is false, so it evaluates to `a--`. Since that's a post-decrement, the decrement happens after its value is provided, so it evaluates to the `100` value that `b` had before it was decremented. Thus `b` gets this value.

So in the first example, the result of evaluating `a--` is assigned to `b`. In the second example, the result of evaluating `(a>100)` is assigned to `b`.

Answer (score 4):

In the first case,

`b= (a>100)?a++:a--;`

can be thought of as following in simple terms:

```
if(a>100) {
   b = a;
   a = a + 1;
}
else {
   b = a;
   a = a - 1;
}
```

In the second case,

`b= (a>100)`

the boolean operation `a>100` returns false which is equivalent to 0. So b will get a value of 0, not 1.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, both `a--` and `a++` evaluate to the *old*, *original* value of `a`. This is how postfix operators behave. The original value of `a` is `100`.

So, regardless of how your `?:` plays out, `b` is assigned the original value of `a`, which is `100`. In that sense the resultant value of `b` is not affected by `?:` operator at all.