# Explanation of if statement

Tags: c#

I am new in C#. looks like below code is in C. Could some please explain below if statement

```
if ((!csentry.get_Item("UR.Action").get_IsPresent() ? false : csentry.get_Item("UR.Action").get_Value() == "Disable"))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the ternary operator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463155/how-does-the-ternary-operator-work)

Comment: It's code that's been compiled and then decompiled back to C# without access to referenced assemblies. This often happens in ILSpy; when you add the referenced assemblies and the types become available, the property metadata allows it to translate to property accesses.

Answer (score 5):

It breaks down to the following. Which is 1000 times more readable than what you had

```
var urlAction = csentry["UR.Action"];

if (urlAction.IsPresent && urlAction.Value == "Disable")
{
     // then do stuff
}
```

<sub>***Note*** : see [@madreflection](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5394572/madreflection)'s comments on the post for an understanding of why this maybe mangled so badly</sub>

> <sub>*it's code that's been compiled and then decompiled back to C# without
>   access to referenced assemblies. This often happens in ILSpy; when you
>   add the referenced assemblies and the types become available, the
>   property metadata allows it to translate to property accesses*</sub>

---

**Additional Resources**

[?: Operator (C# Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator))

> The conditional operator `?:`, commonly known as the ternary conditional
>   operator, evaluates a Boolean expression, and returns the result of
>   evaluating one of two expressions, depending on whether the Boolean
>   expression evaluates to true or false

Comment: I was just thinking about this.

Comment: The decompiled code lacks property metadata. See my edit.

Comment: @RajatKansal im listening... intently

Comment: @RajatKansal If you think this is wrong I get the feeling you probably don't know how the ternary operator works. This is functionally the same as OP's code. Although in the future I recommend explaining why you think something is wrong, just saying it's wrong isn't helpful.

Comment: Hi oksometimes we may get confuse

Answer (score 0):

An if statement basically says if a condition is met, do this. In this instance, it is saying:

IF `!csentry.get_Item("UR.Action").get_IsPresent() ? false : csentry.get_Item("UR.Action").get_Value()` is equal to `"Disable"`, do a result that isn't included.

Really more info is needed to give you the exact answer. But once you realize how they work, if statements are simple. The basic format is:

```
if (condition) {
   result
}
```

Say I had to do a simple response program for a someone saying "hi"

```
if (input == 'hi') {
   printf("hello");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here as for If it's evaluating a ternary operation.

From a very high level, it looks like ***!csentry.get_Item("UR.Action").get_IsPresent()*** if the UR.Action is present then the if condition will not executed. And if it not present then this condition get evaluated ***csentry.get_Item("UR.Action").get_Value() == "Disable"*** if that true then the if block get executed else it'll not get executed.

When you get time take a look at [ternary_operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) for more details