# Ternary Operation in C

Tags: c, conditional-operator, ansi-c

I have a technical question regarding the ternary operation in C.
Let's assume we have the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define M(a, b) (b? (a / b) : (a + b))
int main()
{
   int x = 10, y = 3;
   printf("%d\n" , M(x + y , x - y));
}
```

in the macro, what is the meaning of the question b?
Also , I know that the final answer is 7, but how is it 7?

Comment: `b ?` means if `b` is true, i.e. if `b != 0`. In  this case do division, otherwise perform addition

Comment: you'll want parenthesis: `(b)?`, which would be equivalent to `(10-3)?` aka your idea of `7?...`. That said it's a conditional expression, and for integers this evaluates the "truthiness" of the value, aka non-zero

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463155/how-does-the-ternary-operator-work ?

Comment: Also be aware that `M(X, Y)` is textually subsituted before the actual compilation: so the compiler sees this: `(x -y ? (x + y / x - y) : (x + y + x - y))`

Answer (score 3):

It is not the "question b", that is the syntax of ternary operator

```
expr ? true_expr : false_expr
```

In your case, after macro substitution your code really becomes

```
int main()
{
   int x = 10, y = 3;
   printf("%d\n" , (x - y? (x + y / x - y) : (x + y + x - y));
}
```

Since `x - y` is 7, this becomes true because it is not `0`. `true_expr` executes next which is `(x + y / x - y)` in your case. Substituting values, this evaluates to `10 + 3 / 10 - 3` => `10 + 0 - 3`, which reduces to `7`.

Answer (score 0):

Ternary operator is shorter version of if-else

`return (b? (a / b) : (a + b)`

would be

```
if (b)
{
   -> a/b
}
else
{
   -> a+b
}
```

Generaly, ternary operator looks like this:
`(expression ? if_expression_is_true : else)`

So `b?` is just `b` expression