# Statement with ? in C

Tags: c, syntax, ternary-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use the conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392932/how-do-i-use-the-conditional-operator)

I’m new to C language, and in one of the sample codes I was reviewing I faced the statement:

```
A = A ? B: C[0]
```

I was just wondering what the task of the previous statement is and what will be the result after execution of the mentioned statement.

Comment: Same as [How do I use the conditional operator?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392932/how-do-i-use-the-ternary-operator).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's called a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation). `expr ? a : b` returns `a` if `expr` is true, `b` if false. `expr` can be a boolean expression (e.g. `x > 3`), a boolean literal/variable or anything castable to a boolean (e.g. an int).

`int ret = expr ? a : b` is equivalent to the following:

```
int ret;
if (expr) ret = a;
else ret = b;
```

The nice thing about the ternary operator is that it's an expression, whereas the above are statements, and you can nest expressions but not statements. So you can do things like `ret = (expr ? a : b) > 0;`

As an extra tidbit, Python >=2.6 has a slightly different syntax for an equivalent operation: `a if expr else b`.

Answer (score 4):

It assigns to `A` the value of `B` if `A` is true, otherwise `C[0]`.

[`?:`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

Answer (score 3):

`result = a > b ? x : y;` is identical to this block:

```
if (a > b) {
  result = x;
}
else
{
  result = y;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's the same as an `if else` statement.

It could be rewritten as:

```
if ( A != 0 )
{
    A = B;
}
else
{
    A = C[ 0 ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A gets assigned to B if A exists (not NULL), otherwise C[0].

Comment: -1 the inexistence of A makes the code not even compile. A can be `NULL`, `0` (int), `0.0` (double), etc ...

Comment: And it's B gets assigned to A.

Comment: Thought it was implied that if I said not NULL that I was refering to a pointer, not a double, int, etc.  And A gets assigned to B, not vice versa.

Comment: @Neil: B does not change value with the expression in this question. Neither does C ... A (possibly) changes value.

Comment: A gets assigned to B.  At what point did I say that B changes (or even C for that matter)?  A takes on the value of B is what I meant by that.

Comment: @Neil: you're using the English language in an unusual way: in "A gets assigned to B" it is B that changes value. Compare with "The prize was assigned to Mark" ... :-)

Comment: I know.  :(  I only understood that second interpretation now.

Answer (score 1):

if A equal 0 then A = C[0] else A = B