# Does the ternary operator exist in R?

Tags: r, operators

As the question asks, is there a control sequence in R similar to C's [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/392946/168775)? If so, how do you use it? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want something more powerful than `ifelse`, or just a  more compact form?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Mostly more compact form; simply a way to save writing `if (x>1) y=2 else y=3`. Writing `y=` once has a certain appeal to it.

Answer (score 365, accepted):

As `if` is function in `R` and returns the latest evaluation, if-else is equivalent to `?:`.

```
> a <- 1
> x <- if(a==1) 1 else 2
> x
[1] 1
> x <- if(a==2) 1 else 2
> x
[1] 2
```

The power of R is vectorization. The vectorization of the ternary operator is `ifelse`:

```
> a <- c(1, 2, 1)
> x <- ifelse(a==1, 1, 2)
> x
[1] 1 2 1
> x <- ifelse(a==2, 1, 2)
> x
[1] 2 1 2
```

---

Just kidding, you can define c-style `?:`:

```
`?` <- function(x, y)
    eval(
      sapply(
        strsplit(
          deparse(substitute(y)), 
          ":"
      ), 
      function(e) parse(text = e)
    )[[2 - as.logical(x)]])
```

here, you don't need to take care about brackets:

```
> 1 ? 2*3 : 4
[1] 6
> 0 ? 2*3 : 4
[1] 4
> TRUE ? x*2 : 0
[1] 2
> FALSE ? x*2 : 0
[1] 0
```

but you need brackets for assignment :(

```
> y <- 1 ? 2*3 : 4
[1] 6
> y
[1] 1
> y <- (1 ? 2*3 : 4)
> y
[1] 6
```

---

Finally, you can do very similar way with c:

```
`?` <- function(x, y) {
  xs <- as.list(substitute(x))
  if (xs[[1]] == as.name("<-")) x <- eval(xs[[3]])
  r <- eval(sapply(strsplit(deparse(substitute(y)), ":"), function(e) parse(text = e))[[2 - as.logical(x)]])
  if (xs[[1]] == as.name("<-")) {
    xs[[3]] <- r
        eval.parent(as.call(xs))
  } else {
    r
  }
}
```

You can get rid of brackets:

```
> y <- 1 ? 2*3 : 4
> y
[1] 6
> y <- 0 ? 2*3 : 4
> y
[1] 4
> 1 ? 2*3 : 4
[1] 6
> 0 ? 2*3 : 4
[1] 4
```

These are not for daily use, but maybe good for learning some internals of R language.

Answer (score 26):

Like everyone else said, use `ifelse`, but you can define operators so that you nearly have the ternary operator syntax.

```
`%?%` <- function(x, y) list(x = x, y = y)
`%:%` <- function(xy, z) if(xy$x) xy$y else z

TRUE %?% rnorm(5) %:% month.abb
## [1]  0.05363141 -0.42434567 -0.20000319  1.31049766 -0.31761248
FALSE %?% rnorm(5) %:% month.abb
## [1] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec"
# or, more generally
condition %?% value1 %:% value2
```

It actually works if you define the operators without the `%` signs, so you could have

```
`?` <- function(x, y) if(x) y[[1]] else y[[2]]
`:` <- function(y, z) list(y, z)

TRUE ? rnorm(5) : month.abb
## [1]  1.4584104143  0.0007500051 -0.7629123322  0.2433415442  0.0052823403
FALSE ? rnorm(5) : month.abb
## [1] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec"
```

(This works because the precedence of `:` is lower than `?`.)

Unfortunately, that then breaks the existing help and sequence operators.

Answer (score 10):

`if` works like unvectorised ifelse if used in following manner:

```
`if`(condition, doIfTrue, doIfFalse)
```

The advantage of using this over ifelse is when the vectorisation is in the way (i.e I have scalar boolean and list/vector things as a result)

```
ifelse(TRUE, c(1,2), c(3,4))
[1] 1
`if`(TRUE, c(1,2), c(3,4))
[1] 1 2
```

Answer (score 7):

I would take a look at the `ifelse` command. I would call it even better because it is also vectorized. An example using the cars dataset:

```
> cars$speed > 20
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[25] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[37] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[49]  TRUE  TRUE

> ifelse(cars$speed > 20, 'fast', 'slow')
 [1] "slow" "slow" "slow" "slow" "slow" "slow" "slow" "slow" "slow" "slow"
[11] "slow" "slow" "slow" "slow" "slow" "slow" "slow" "slow" "slow" "slow"
[21] "slow" "slow" "slow" "slow" "slow" "slow" "slow" "slow" "slow" "slow"
[31] "slow" "slow" "slow" "slow" "slow" "slow" "slow" "slow" "slow" "slow"
[41] "slow" "slow" "slow" "fast" "fast" "fast" "fast" "fast" "fast" "fast"
```

Comment: Hi Paul -- did you mean to show something about `ifelse` with your example? ;)

Answer (score 5):

Just as a prank, you *can* redefine the `?` operator to (almost) work like the ternary operator (THIS IS A BAD IDEA):

```
`?` <- function(x, y) { y <-substitute(y); if(x) eval(y[[2]], parent.frame()) else eval(y[[3]], parent.frame()) }

x <- 1:3
length(x) ? (x*2) : 0
x <- numeric(0)
length(x) ? (x*2) : 0

for(i in 1:5) cat(i, (i %% 2) ? "Odd\n" : "Even\n")
```

... But you need to put the expressions in parentheses because the default precedence isn't like in C.

Just remember to restore the old help function when you're done playing:

```
rm(`?`)
```

Answer (score 4):

Your link points to an `if` statement.

```
> x <- 1
> if(x < 2) print("Less than") else print("Greater than")
[1] "Less than"
```

If your input variable is a vector, then `ifelse` might be more suitable:

```
> x <- 1:3
> ifelse(x<=2, "Less than or equal", "Greater than")
[1] "Less than or equal" "Less than or equal" "Greater than"
```

---

To access the help page for `if`, you need to embed the `if` in backticks:

```
?`if`
```

The help page for `ifelse` is at:

```
`?ifelse`
```

Comment: As @kohske said, this will work too: `print(if (x<2) "Less than" else "Greater than")`

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't explicitly exist, but you can do:

```
set.seed(21)
y <- 1:10
z <- rnorm(10)

condition1 <- TRUE
x1 <- if(condition1) y else z
```

or

```
condition2 <- sample(c(TRUE,FALSE),10,TRUE)
x2 <- ifelse(condition2, y, z)
```

The difference between the two is that `condition1` must be a logical vector of length 1, while `condition2` must be a logical vector the same length as `x`, `y`, and `z`.  The first will return either `y` or `z` (the entire object), while the second will return the corresponding element of `y` (`condition2==TRUE`) or `z` (`condition2==FALSE`).

Also note that `ifelse` will be slower than `if` / `else` if `condition`, `y`, and `z` are all vectors with length 1.

Comment: thanks Joshua, your answer helped a lot, I found answer from post you mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/a/8792474/3019570

Answer (score 4):

tidyverse has if_else() function in the dplyr library. Compared to the base ifelse(), this function is more strict. It checks that true and false are the same type. This strictness makes the output type more predictable, and makes it somewhat faster.

```
if_else(a == 1, 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written a small language extension which emulates C's conditional ternary operator in R. It can be installed as a package from [here](https://github.com/grddavies/rtern)

The implementation is based on the [answer given by @kohske](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8790269/12879453), but I have made some changes so that it is robust to cases when the *if_true* and *if_false* arguments contain a colon, allows conditional statements to be chained and retains the base functionality of the `?` operator.

I will refer to others' warnings about the dangers of redefining operators, but it's a neat example of how dynamic a language R can be!