# counting the even numbers in an array of integers using recursion

Tags: java, arrays

I want to find the number of even numbers in an array of integers.
so far i wrote this code

```
public static int EvenNum(int[] arr) {
    int index = 0;
    if (arr[index] % 2 == 1) {
        return 0;
    } else if (arr[index] % 2 == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    index++;
    return index + EvenNum(arr);
}
```

please help me make this code run

Comment: What does help me run imply?  Get you a compiler?

Comment: What _specifically_ doesn't you understand? Have you used a debugger?

Comment: `please help me make this code run` try this :) `public static void main(String[] args){System.out.println(EvenNum(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5}));}`

Comment: why do you need recursion at all?

Comment: each time i run the code i get " " (nothing but space) @Pshemo

Comment: when i run the meathod i get space, i dont know why i can't get any number or the counting.. here is what i wrote in my main method System.out.println("The Even Numbers in array are: ");
        EvenNum(array); /// i asked my teacher and he told me that i am counting even number. my logic is correct but this time, the index is used to control the recursion call..... i dont understand what he meant by that @Pshemo

Comment: i need recursion because its  a HW @laymelek

Comment: no i dont use debugger @Sotirios Delimanolis , actually i dont know what is debugger, Im new n coding

Comment: @user3469667 in your code result of `EvenNum(array);` is outside of `System.out.println(...)` which means it will not get printed. You need to place it inside parenthesis and concatenate it with your String information (use `+` operator) like `System.out.println("The Even Numbers in array are: "+EvenNum(array));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an index parameter to know where in the array you are checking.

```
public static int EvenNum(int[] arr, int index)
{
    if (index == arr.length) return 0;  // Stop recursion
    //return (arr[index] % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 0) + EvenNum(arr, index + 1);
    // or....
    int result;
    if ((arr[index] % 2) == 0) {    // Is even
        result = 1;
    }
    else {                          // Is odd
        result = 0;
    }
    return result + EvenNum(arr, index + 1);
}

public static void main(final String... args)
{
    // Start with index = 0
    System.out.println(EvenNum(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5}, 0));
}
```

Comment: please simplfy this (arr[index] % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 0) because im new at coding and i dont know what u mean by  ? 1 : 0 @Johnny Mopp

Comment: @user3469667 Updated my answer. Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392932/how-do-i-use-the-conditional-operator) for info on the ternary operator.

Comment: can you explain or simplify arr[index] % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 0.......... because im new at coding and i dont understand what ? 1 : 0 means @Johnny Mopp

Answer (score -1):

make use of a loop inside the your EvenNum() method:

```
int evenNoCount = 0;
for (int i=0; i<arr.length();i++){
    if(arr[i]%2 == 0)
        evenNoCount++;
}
return evenNoCount;
```

Comment: Question asked for recursion. If you think it is better, give a rationale why at least