# SFINAE doesn't work on a constexpr function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constexpr, enable-if

To support portability I want to choose a constant based on the fact whether `size_t` is 32 bit or 64 bit.
The code:

```
using namespace std;

namespace detail {
    template<enable_if<is_same<size_t, uint32_t>::value,void*>::type = nullptr>
    constexpr static const size_t defaultSizeHelper() {
        return ( (size_t) 1 << 30 ) / 2 * 5; //2,5 Gb
    }
    template<enable_if<is_same<size_t, uint64_t>::value,void*>::type = nullptr>
    constexpr size_t defaultSizeHelper() {
        return numeric_limits<size_t>::max() / 2;
    }
}

constexpr static size_t defaultSize = detail::defaultSizeHelper();
```

This code doesn't compile because of the `error: 'std::enable_if<false, void*>::type' has not been declared. template<enable_if<is_same<size_t, uint64_t>::value,void*>::type = nullptr>`

Compiler - `GCC 4.9`

It seems to me that the compiler doesn't apply a SFINAE principle to a `constexpr`. What should I do then?

Comment: There is also the possibility to use tag dispatching which would be much more elegant for your usage example. `defaultSizeHelper(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof(std::size_t)>{})`

Comment: Just a small addition to my previous comment, your code would look like: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee0738c2369e03ec when using tag dispatching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The Problem

*SFINAE* stands for *Substitution Failure Is Not An Error*.

Neither of your two templates fail during instantiation, instead one of them will fail the second the compiler takes a look at it (because it will see that the *enable_if*s does not depend on a template parameter, and try to expand them directly).

---

#### Solution

The solution is to make the check depend on some *template-parameter*, so that the compiler can only check the condition upon a potential instantiation.

In your case the easiest solution will be to simply provide a *default template-argument* that is the type that you would like to check against (`T` in the below).

```
using namespace std;

namespace detail {
    template<class T = uint32_t, typename enable_if<is_same<size_t, T>::value,void*>::type = nullptr>
    constexpr static const size_t defaultSizeHelper() {
        return ( (size_t) 1 << 30 ) / 2 * 5; //2,5 Gb
    }

    template<class T = uint64_t, typename enable_if<is_same<size_t, T>::value,void*>::type = nullptr>
    constexpr size_t defaultSizeHelper() {
        return numeric_limits<size_t>::max() / 2;
    }
}

constexpr static size_t defaultSize = detail::defaultSizeHelper();
```

> <sub>**Note**: An alternative solution would be to combine the two functions into one, and use the [*ternary-operator*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/392932/1090079) to either return the result of one expression, or another.</sub>.

> <sub>**Note**: Now that the check is dependent on a template-parameter, make sure you understand why you need to use `typename` to disambiguate the enable if. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24101297/1090079) for more information.</sub>

Comment: This solution is better (generally, not in this particular case) because it doesn't introduce an additional dummy (well, not at all) argument.

Answer (score 5):

The principle behind [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) is that if the substitution of a deduced template argument results in ill-formed code, then that function template is dropped from the overload resolution set, instead of causing a hard error.

In your case there is no deduced template argument or substitution of one, hence you end up with compilation errors. All you need is

```
constexpr static size_t defaultSize = is_same<size_t, uint32_t>::value 
                                        ? (( (size_t) 1 << 30 ) / 2 * 5)
                                        : numeric_limits<size_t>::max() / 2;
```

---

For curiosity's sake, if you wanted to use SFINAE, you could do something like this

```
namespace detail {
    template<typename T, typename enable_if<is_same<T, uint32_t>::value,void*>::type = nullptr>
    constexpr static const T defaultSizeHelper(T) {
        return ( (size_t) 1 << 30 ) / 2 * 5; //2,5 Gb
    }
    template<typename T, typename enable_if<is_same<T, uint64_t>::value,void*>::type = nullptr>
    constexpr T defaultSizeHelper(T) {
        return numeric_limits<size_t>::max() / 2;
    }
}

constexpr static size_t defaultSize = detail::defaultSizeHelper(size_t{});
```

Comment: Oh, I've forgot that I can mix up meta-programming and normal code! Thank you for a nice solution!