# really odd problems in palindrome program

Tags: c++

I must take a few words and test to see if they are palindromes, not counting the characters of space, "," and "-".

```
      #include <iostream>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
    int main() 
    {
       int inputs;
       for (int i=0;i<inputs;i++)
      {string str;
      getline(cin, str);
      transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::tolower);
       str.erase(remove_if(str.begin(),str.end(),','),str.end());
       str.erase(remove_if(str.begin(),str.end(),'-'),str.end());
       str.erase(remove_if(str.begin(),str.end(),' '),str.end());
      if (str == string(str.rbegin(), str.rend()))
      cout << "Y ";
      else 
      cout << "N "; }

}
```

the problems: 
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algobase.h:71:0,                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/char_traits.h:39,                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:40,                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,                 from solution.cc:1:/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of 'bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred<_Predicate>::operator()(_Iterator) [with _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; _Predicate = char]':/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algo.h:866:28:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__remove_if(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Predicate) [with _ForwardIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_pred]'/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algo.h:937:47:   required from '_FIter std::remove_if(_FIter, _FIter, _Predicate) [with _FIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator >; _Predicate = char]'solution.cc:12:49:   required from here/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/predefined_ops.h:231:30: error: expression cannot be used as a function  { return bool(_M_pred(*__it)); }                              ^

(complete jibberish to me.)
Any solutions?

Comment: Are you testing each word, or a sequence of words. I'm unclear what the boundary is.

Comment: If you really wanted to do this in C++ and use algorithms, this is a 5 or 6 line program using `std::reverse` and `std::remove_if`.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: *how is it possible that it is always not a palindrome*  -- How is it possible that the first input is a palindrome when the first character 'A' is not equal to the last character 'a', and you have nowhere in your code a conversion of letters to the same case (all upper or all lower)?  That right there is a signal that you should debug your code.  In addition, a whole chunk of code is missing to make the letters the same casing.

Comment: @SimonParker Based on the correct answer, it must be the entire string excluding non alphanumeric.

Comment: Reminder:  In C++, letters are *case sensitive*.  This means 'A' != 'a'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might as well show a solution that contrasts dramatically to your attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

int main() 
{
    std::string orig;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, orig))
    {
        std::transform(orig.begin(), orig.end(), orig.begin(), ::toupper);

        // erase the punctuation and spaces
        orig.erase(std::remove_if(orig.begin(), orig.end(), [](char ch) 
        { return ::isspace(ch) || ::ispunct(ch);}), orig.end()); 

        std::cout << ((orig == std::string(orig.rbegin(), orig.rend()))?"Y":"N");
    }
}
```

Note that `std::reverse` was not needed, and the usage of the `erase / remove_if` idiom to remove the spaces and punctuation.

Comment: I really want to give you a +1 but [using namespace std is poor practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @Serdalis It is not bad practice if used within a module as small as this one.  It is bad practice when it is used in header files, where inclusion of the header will inadvertently bring in stuff you don't want.

Comment: I have still seen it bite people when they include it at the top of a C++ source file. Mostly with small helper functions and such. Just a pet hate I have and off topic, this answer is still great. ( +1 now ).

Comment: @Serdalis No problem.  I changed the code anyway.

Comment: what does the question mark do?

Comment: and why am I getting an extra "y" at the beginning with your code?

Comment: @GoodwinLu [This works correctly](http://ideone.com/XnFnFN).  Maybe because I left out the unnecessary `16` and just processed the strings?  The question mark is the [ternary operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392932/how-do-i-use-the-conditional-operator)

Comment: @GoodwinLu [Using your original data without the 16](http://ideone.com/O5UC25)

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Just take an editor and erase that input line.

Answer (score 3):

Check for palindrome can be as simple as

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main() {

  std::string str, rStr;

  std::cout << "Enter String :\n";
  std::cin >> str;

  std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::tolower);
  rStr = str;
  std::reverse(begin(str), end(str));

  (rStr == str) ? std::cout << "Word is palindrone\n" : std::cout << "Word is not palindrone\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Modify as you wish.

To get more than one word as input, use `getline(cin, str);`