# Reading from text file to structure

Tags: c++, c++11

Firstly, I'd like to explain what I'm trying to do. So, I have a text file with 10 names followed by their points. I'm trying to create a structure and read information from a file using a function (void). And that's my code and text file:

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void read(struct laLiga t[]) {
    ifstream infile("info.txt");
    int i = 0;
    while(infile >> t.team[i] >> t.points[i]) {
        infile.get(t.team);
        infile >> t.points;
        i++;
    }
}

struct laLiga {
    char team[50];
    int points;
};

int main() {
    struct laLiga t[10];
    read(t);
    return 0;
}
```

text file:

```
Athletic Bilbao  15
Atletico Madrid  18
Barcelona  16
Alaves  10
Las Palmas  12
Real Madrid  18
Real Sociedad  10
Sevilla  17
Eibar  11
Villarreal  16
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `std::vector` to make things easier:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

auto file_text = 
R"(Athletic Bilbao  15
Atletico Madrid  18
Barcelona  16
Alaves  10
Las Palmas  12
Real Madrid  18
Real Sociedad  10
Sevilla  17
Eibar  11
Villarreal  16)";

struct laLiga {
    std::string team;
    int points;
};

void read(std::vector<laLiga>& t) {
    //ifstream infile("info.txt"); // would also work
    std::stringstream infile{file_text};
    while(infile) {
        laLiga laliga{};
        std::string partial_team_name{};
        while(!(infile >> laliga.points)) { // keep going until we get the points
            infile.clear(); // we could not read points, infile stream now in error; clearing to continue
            if(infile >> partial_team_name) // maybe the next string is part of a team name
                laliga.team += (laliga.team.empty() ? "" : " ") + partial_team_name; // add to team name with space if there was something already in there
            else
                return; // no points, no team, we're done
        }
        t.push_back(laliga); // after we get the points we can add the team
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<laLiga> t;
    read(t);
    for(auto i : t) {
        std::cout << std::setw(30) << i.team;
        std::cout << std::setw(10) << i.points << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
       Athletic Bilbao        15
       Atletico Madrid        18
             Barcelona        16
                Alaves        10
            Las Palmas        12
           Real Madrid        18
         Real Sociedad        10
               Sevilla        17
                 Eibar        11
            Villarreal        16
```

[live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3036d61711cc0fd6)

Comment: Hey, thanks for a good suggestion, I'm talking about vectors. Everything looks good, but I need some more explanation. First of all, I do not understand how this condition works: "!(infile >> laliga.points)". Secondly, I do not understand why we need to clear the file and what changes. Lastly, could you explain how does this work: ' laliga.team.empty() ? "" : " " '

Comment: `!(infile >> laliga.points)` means read from `infile` to `points`. If `infile >> laliga.points` fails then it will evaluate to `false`. `!(infile >> laliga.points)` will be `true` if we cannot read points so then the program will continue to try and read part of a team name.

Comment: `infile.clear();` leaves `infile` unchanged except for the flags. The flags are cleared. After `infile >> laliga.points` fails (could not read points) we must clear the error flags of `infile` to try reading again.

Comment: `(laliga.team.empty() ? "" : " ")` is a [ternary conditional operator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/392946/1460794). If there is no team name yet, then it returns `""` (no space), else it returns `" "` (one space). So if `laliga.team` is empty then we add `partial_team_name`, otherwise we add `" " + partial_team_name`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to define the structure *before* you use it in the `read` function.

Secondly, in the `read` function it is the variable `t` that is an array, not its members. So you should be using `t[i].team` and `t[i].points`.

Thirdly, you have already read the data from the file with the `>>` operators in the loop condition. You should not read it *again* inside the loop.

Fourthly, the input file you want to read is actually harder to parse than you think. That is because you can have names both without *and* with spaces in them. Both the `get` function of input streams and the input operator `>>` separates on spaces. You should probably [read the whole line](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and then split it at the last space.

Lastly, and actually a reason I should *not* write an answer is that you haven't actually asked a question, or told us what is wrong with your code. Please [read about how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for future questions.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm sorry for not reading important information before posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to read or write structs in a text file then best would be to use `ifstream` `read()` function and `ofstream` `write()` function. Following is how to use them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring> // for strncpy()

using namespace std;

struct laLiga {
    char team[50];
    int points;
};

int main()
{
struct laLiga t;

strncpy(t.team,"Some Name",sizeof("Some Name"));
t.points = 100;

//do this for writing  a complete struct to a text file at once
ofstream output("info.txt");
output.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&t),sizeof(t));
output.close();

//do this for reading a complete struct from a text file at once

struct laLiga T;

ifstream input("info.txt");
input.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&T),sizeof(T));
input.close();

//now T will hold both the name and points fields from the text file without doing it individually

cout << "Name = " <<T.team << endl;
cout << "Points = " << T.points << endl;

return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT (Console)**

```
   Name = Some Name

   Points = 100
```

Both `read()` and `write()` function's first parameter should be `char*` that is why we use `reinterpret_cast` to cast the complete struct to sequence of bytes and then write to file.
Only drawback of doing like this is that the text file will be unreadable when opened in windows as it wont be normal text but reading and writing would be much easier.