# C++ columns, line up perfectly

Tags: c++, multiple-columns

So I'm trying to write this code that displays ASCII code in perfect columns, but the columns are perfectly lined up right know. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>   // cout
#include <iomanip>    // setw

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int a;                                                                    
    for(a=32;a<=255;++a)
    {
        cout << a << setw(2) <<static_cast<char>(a)<< setw(20);              
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is how I want it to look like, 
http://www.asciitable.com/index/extend.gif

Comment: You don't have any newlines in your output?

Comment: also you should set the first setw to 3 since you are going to 255 :)

Comment: @AndyG how do I create new lines then?

Comment: add << endl where you want a new line..

Comment: @MarkusFürst Would you mind to show us your expected and actual output? I don't get what you're asking about.

Comment: A newline can be inserted with either `'\n'` (newline escape code) or `std::endl` (inserts `'\n'` and flushes output).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ 
Can't show you here in the comment since its to long.

Comment: @MarkusFürst I can't spot what's your output or expected output in your question, just a vague sentence _"columns are perfectly lined up right know"_ What does that mean? _"Can't show you here in the comment since its to long."_ [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40851126/edit)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>   // cout
#include <iomanip>    // setw

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a;
    int count = 0;
    for (a = 32; a <= 255; ++a)
    {
        cout << a << setw(2) << static_cast<char>(a);
        if (count != 3)
        {
            cout << setw(20);
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            count = 0;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

PS: if you want to have more columns that are equally long try to change this `if (count != 3)` and this `cout << setw(20);` to something like `if (count != 6)` and `cout << setw(9);`

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be a bit long, so... working code is at the bottom, everything before it is an explanation.

1. **Columns**: A simple approach to having *n* columns in the same line is to conditionally insert a newline after every *n* entries.  The easiest way to do this is to use modulo arithmetic, treating the first entry as `1` and checking if the remainder when dividing by *n* is `0`.

   ```
       const int NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 5;

       // ...

       for(a=32;a<=255;++a)
       {
           cout << /* output... */
                << ((a - 31) % NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS == 0 ? "\n" : "");
       }
   ```

   How this works: We add or subtract from the loop's to treat it as if it started at 1 (in this case, by subtracting 31 because it starts at 32), then use modulo on that value to determine whether it's cleanly divisible by *n*.  If it is, we insert `"\n"` (newline); if it's not, we insert `""` (nothing).

   This can also be modified to always output a newline at the end of the loop, without placing `cout << endl;` or `cout << '\n';` outside the loop.

   ```
   // Change...
   << ((a - 31) % NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS == 0 ? "\n" : "");
   // To...
   << ((a - 31) % NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS == 0 || a == 255 ? "\n" : "");
   // Inserts "\n" every n columns, OR when a is 255.
   ```

   Alternatively, you can place the check at the start of the output, and treat the loop's counter as if it started with 0; in this case, we would subtract 32.

   ```
       const int NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 5;

       // ...

       for(a=32;a<=255;++a)
       {
           cout << ((a - 32) % NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS == 0 ? "\n" : "")
                << /* output... */;
       }
   ```

   This will place a newline at the very start of the output, although if that isn't desired, it can be avoided by specifically checking that `a` isn't actually its starting value.

   ```
   // Change...
   ((a - 32) % NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS == 0 ? "\n" : "")
   // To...
   ((a - 32) % NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS == 0 && a != 32 ? "\n" : "")
   // Inserts "\n" every n columns, unless a is 32.
   ```

   You can also modify this approach to let the user specify how many columns they want to display, if you so desire.
2. **Spacing**: If you pass `std::setw()` a constant value, it can mess up your formatting in certain places.  As it stands, there are two issues with the spacing.

   ```
   for(a=32;a<=255;++a)
   {
       cout << a
            << setw(2)   // Doesn't take into account the number of digits in a.
            <<static_cast<char>(a)
            << setw(20); // Doesn't take into account character 127 not being a graphical
                         //  character.
   }
   ```

   As an alternative, you can output tabs with `\t`, change which output you apply `std::setw()` to, or use a little logic to determine what value to pass `std::setw()`.

   1. The first one won't properly line up if the width is a constant.  This is because `std::setw()` affects the next output after it, and casting to `char` guarantees that this output will always be exactly one character (and therefore, that if you specify width *x*, it will be padded with *x* - 1 spaces).  There are two ways to solve this: Use `std::setw()` and `std::left` before outputting `a`...

      ```
      cout << setw(4) << left // Tells cout to make sure a is at least 4 characters,
                              //  padding it at the end if necessary.
                              // 4 characters are used to account for 3 digits + a space.
           << a
           << /* output... */;
      ```

      Or apply `std::setw()` to `static_cast<char>(a)`, as you currently are, but use a little logic to determine the value...

      ```
      cout << a
           << setw(a < 100 ? 3 : 2)           // Set width to 3 if a < 100, or 2 otherwise.
           << static_cast<char>(a)
           << /* output... */;
      ```

      If we go with the first one, it may be better to move `std::left` outside the loop, as so:

      ```
      cout << left;
      for(a=32;a<=255;++a)
      {
          cout << setw(4)
               << /* output.. */;
      }
      cout << right; // Reset to default.
      ```

      Since we're not passing `std::right` or `std::internal` inside the loop, there's no reason to pass `std::left` every single time.
   2. On some platforms, character 127 will break the formatting of everything after it, until the end of the line; this is because it isn't actually a graphical character, and thus won't actually be displayed (Unicode has "DEL", and Win32 console fonts have a house, though, so they can display it graphically).  The simplest way to work around this is to output one or more tab stops, or `\t`s, after `static_cast<char>(a)`.

      ```
      cout << /* output... */
           << static_cast<char>(a)
           << "\t\t"
           << /* output... */;
      ```
3. **[Wait, what's that `?:` thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/392946/5386374)**: That would be the [*conditional operator*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator), unofficially known as the "ternary operator".  [This operator takes 3 operands, and acts like a miniature `if ... else` statement that can be used as an expression](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/14631/).  It is used as:

   *condition* `?` *true-result* `:` *false-result*

   *condition* is converted to `bool`, and can be anything that can evaluate to a boolean value.  If `true`, the operator evaluates to *true-result*; if `false`, it evaluates to *false-result*.  This operator looks a bit weird, but is incredibly useful, since it allows conditional logic to be applied in situations where `if` statements can't be used (such as during variable assignment).

   Here, I used it twice:

   - To conditionally insert a newline into `std::cout`, after every *n* columns.  Note that it is enclosed in parentheses; this is because [it has lower precedence than the `<<` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).  It evaluates to either `"\n"` or the empty string `""`, depending on the value of `a`.
   - To determine the value to pass `std::setw()`, if it's applied to `static_cast<char>(a)` instead of `a`.  It evaluates to 3 if `a` is less than 100, or `2` otherwise.

---

So, combining these, we get a final result that looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>   // cout
#include <iomanip>    // setw, left, right

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    const int NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 8; // Number of columns per line.

    cout << left; // Append padding after output.
    int a;
    for(a=32;a<=255;++a)
    {
        cout << setw(4)                         // Pad until 4 characters.
             << a
             << static_cast<char>(a)
             << "\t\t"                          // Use tabs for spacing.
             << ((a - 31) % NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS == 0 || a == 255 ? "\n" : "");
               // Insert newline when specified, and after outputting the last entry.
    }
    // This isn't necessary since you exit right after, but it's a useful habit to develop
    //  if you format text for console output frequently.
    // Remove if desired.
    cout << right; // Reset to default.

    return 0;
}
```

<sup>I would also suggest:

1) Moving the `using namespace std;` inside `main()` itself, and/or replacing it with:

    `using std::cout; using std::left; using std::right; using std::setw;`

2) Declaring `a` inside the `for` loop's condition, as `for(int a=32;a<=255;++1)`.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

I think that you are looking for something like this:

```
#include <iostream>   // cout
#include <iomanip>    // setw

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int a;                                                                    
    for(a=32;a<=255;++a)
    {
        cout << setw(3) << a << setw(20) <<static_cast<char>(a) << std::endl;              
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`setw(3)` comes before the character, and you want 3 instead of 2 as mentioned in the comments.
And you also forgot to print a newline at the end.

To get something that looks like the link, you can do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>   // cout
#include <iomanip>    // setw

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int a;
    int nColumns = 14;
    for(a=32;a<=255;++a)
    {
        cout << setw(10) << a << setw(8) <<static_cast<char>(a);
        if((a-31)%nColumns == 0)
        {
            cout<<endl;    
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My online compiler does not show characters from 130 to 255 so a break appears (columns not lining up after 130). If yours can show correctly every character, you should not see any break.

[Example](http://rextester.com/JMERNN63187)

Comment: Thanks that helps! But that only creates two columns what if I want like 14 columns that are equally long.

Comment: @MarkusFürst I'm not sure I understand correctly, can you write a small example ? But I think I would simply add an if statement in the for loop, and look at (a-32)%14 for example. Every time this number is equal to 0, you print the newline

Comment: Look at the link I posted in the original question :)

Comment: @MarkusFürst Could you explain ? As far as I know, the code compiles and output something coherent. You can have a look [here](http://rextester.com/JMERNN63187).

Comment: @MarkusFürst Number of columns might be too big or width to large for your screen, so it might look like it's going on a new line when it should not. Play with these numbers and let me know.

Comment: I think the problem is as you said that the columns is too big for my screen or something. The link that you posted, the columns were great until 128.

Comment: That's what I said in the post. The online compiler does not know how to print those chars, so the garbage output is bigger than a normal char. I can't verify that, but I believe that a screen outputting the real chars would keep the width just fine.

Comment: Thanks for all the help!

Comment: The formatting issue starting at 128 & later is caused by the "delete" control character (ASCII 127), which isn't actually a graphical character (although Unicode displays it as "DEL", and Windows' Win32 console fonts display it as a house).

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned before in the comments, you need to ask `std::cout`for the correct width before outputting the value, and you need to have a means to output a new line, when you have a certain number of columns. So here is just a small edit to your code (this will have numbers increasing in the row, if you want the values to increase in a column instead of a row, you need to do a bit more math or instead of outputting values directly, have them appended to a string for each line, and then output the values at the end. I'll add the first solution to the end of this answer, since the row-increment answer was already given by someone else :-) ):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int nocols = 5;    // number of columns that you want
    for (int a = 32; a < 256; ++a)
    {
        cout << setw(3) << a << setw(20) << static_cast<char>(a);
        if (!((a - 31) % nocols))
            cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is a go at column-increment format:

```
int nocols = 8;    // number of columns that you want
int norows = 1 + (256 - 32 - 1) / nocols; // number of rows

for (int row = 0; row < norows; ++row)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < nocols; ++col)
    {
        int ch = 32 + norows * col + row;
        if (ch < 256)
            cout << setw(3) << ch << setw(10) << static_cast<char>(ch) << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried your code ? The output does not look good. And setw(2) is not enough as he goes up to 255.

Comment: @RolandIllig Thanks, fixed it, I also had the formula for `ch` wrong, it was going row by row. Now it should go column by column, and also stop outputting when ch is larger than 255.

Comment: It is still wrong. `norows` should be `(256 - 32 + nocols - 1) / nocols`.

Comment: @RolandIllig I see, mine prints an extra line when number of characters that are being printed is divisible by the number of columns. Thanks, fixed it.