# what does "( (x<y) ? 0 : (x-y) ) ." means in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

this is a function.

```
int find(int x, int y){
    return( (x<y) ? 0 : (x-y) );
    }
```

when we execute `find(x,find(x,y))` , it will give minimum of x and y. I'm not getting how this is executing to give the minimum.
what does `"( (x<y) ? 0 : (x-y) ) ."` means in C++?

Comment: It's a ternary expression with the conditional operator.

Comment: Shorthand for `if (x<y) { return 0; } else { return (x-y); }`

Comment: *when we execute `find(x,find(x,y))` , it will give minimum of `x` and `y`.* Actually, it doesn't. `find(-1, find(-1, 1))` gives 0. It only works for non-negative `x` and `y`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use the conditional (ternary) operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392932/how-do-i-use-the-conditional-ternary-operator)

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting code to find a minimum and it works!

**The only restriction, numbers must be positive!**

The meaning is simple: when `x < y` we return `0`, otherwise we return `x - y`.

Now, consider all possible cases with 0 < x, y:

x < y:

```
    find(x, find(x,y)) == find(x, 0) == x - 0 == x == min(x, y)
```

x == y:

```
    find(x, find(x,y)) == find(x, x - y) == find(x, 0) == x - 0 == x == min(x, y)
```

x > y:

```
    find(x, find(x,y)) == find(x, x - y) == x - (x - y) == y == min(x, y)
```

With negative numbers it does not work.

Comment: It works for cases x, y >= 0. So it works for non-negative numbers.

Comment: agree, but the proof will require more entries :-) the main point, it does not work for nagatives

Comment: Your examples you say "with negative numbers it does not work". 0 isn't negative and it works in your examples. So you did cover it. It doesn't require more entries. "numbers must be positive" simply isn't true. :)

Comment: Well... agree. BTW we can extend it to negatives: the expression returns minimum of this union set: {0 U {x, y > 0}} (zero positive part of x, y) :-)