# How to understand ternary operator? For example #define MAX(x, y) ((x) > (y) ? (x) : (y))

Tags: c, conditional-operator

I have seen someone wrote this code `#define MAX(x, y) ((x) > (y) ? (x) : (y))`
What does it mean?

Comment: What's not to understand? If x is larger than y, then the maximum is x, otherwise it's y. Is it the ternary operator or the #define you don't understand? (And why all those brackets?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use the conditional (ternary) operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392932/how-do-i-use-the-conditional-ternary-operator)

Answer (score 3):

Here it checks if `x` is greater than `y` if yes then `x` else `y`.

Let's look at a example to understand it

```
int max = x > y ? x : y
```

It simply means

```
if (x > y)
  max = x
else 
  max = y
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Ternary Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) is syntactic sugar of writing if-else. You can see this as `( expression )? (result to be stored if true): (result to be stored if false)`. So to answer your question `#define MAX(x, y) ((x) > (y) ? (x) : (y))` returns x if x is greater than y else returns y.

EDIT:
Changed reference link, and rephrased the sentences.

Comment: It's called the conditional operator, not the ternary operator. You should have linked the page you linked.

Comment: “Return” generally means that a statement returns from a function call. This is a misleading term to use when discussion an expression. An operator has a result value or produces a result or evaluates to a result. It does not return a value.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the link. I remember reading it as "ternary" or "conditional" operator hence I used the word. And @EricPostpischil thanks for the clarification on return, will change it.