# I do not understand this C notation

Tags: c, syntax

Can someone explain this kind of statement(s)? I didn't get it.

```
  data[i] = ((data[i] == div[i]) ? '0' : '1');
```

Comment: If `data[i]` is the same as `div[i]` it gets 0, otherwise it gets 1

Comment: See [conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/392932/238704

Answer (score 3):

It's an if-else statement but the conditional operator takes less space and helps to write the if-else statements in the shortest way possible.

So , your expression can be visualized into if-else statement as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
// Code ...
if(data[i]==div[i])
    data[i]='0';
else
    data[i]='1';
}
```

** ‘?:’ takes three operands to work, hence they are also called ternary operators.